# How can you Pickle multiple objects in one file?

Tags: python, pickle

In my case, I wish to pickle (using `pickle.dump()`) two separate lists to a file, then retrieve these from a separate file, however when using `pickle.load()` I have struggled finding where one list ends and the next begins as I simply don't know how to `pickle.dump()` them in a manner that makes them easy to retrieve, even after looking through documentation.

Comment: Have you tried writing them as sublists in an enclosing list e.g. `my_list = [[list_1], [list_2]])` or similar or in some way incorporate them into a single data structure to pickle?

Comment: If you pickle two lists one after another in the same file with `pickle.dump(l1,f); pickle.dump(l2,f)`, then you can unpickle them in the same order from the same file with `l1=pickle.load(f); l2=pickle.load(f)`. Pickle will find where one ends and the other starts.

Comment: Ill try that out, thank you. If that doesn't work Ill use sublists, which I didn't think of.

Comment: Why not pickle a tuple of your lists? `pickle.dump((l1, l2), fh)` and `l1, l2 = pickle.load(fh)`?

Comment: Thank you I got it to work! Ill try using some of your other suggestions to make it as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`pickle` will read them in the same order you dumped them in.

```
import pickle

test1, test2 = ["One", "Two", "Three"], ["1", "2", "3"]
with open("C:/temp/test.pickle","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(test1, f)
    pickle.dump(test2, f)
with open("C:/temp/test.pickle", "rb") as f:
    testout1 = pickle.load(f)
    testout2 = pickle.load(f)

print testout1, testout2
```

Prints out `['One', 'Two', 'Three'] ['1', '2', '3']`. To pickle an arbitrary number of objects, or to just make them easier to work with, you can put them in a tuple, and then you only have to pickle the one object.

```
import pickle

test1, test2 = ["One", "Two", "Three"], ["1", "2", "3"]
saveObject = (test1, test2)
with open("C:/temp/test.pickle","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(saveObject, f)
with open("C:/temp/test.pickle", "rb") as f:
    testout = pickle.load(f)

print testout[0], testout[1]
```

Prints out `['One', 'Two', 'Three'] ['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Thank you, I now know pickle reads them in the order they were pickled.

Comment: a tip for people landing here wanting to save multiple dataframes into one pickle. You can similarly to the above, but saving all the dataframes into a dictionary: `df_dicts = { }` then `df_dicts[0], df_dicts[1], df_dicts[2] = df1, df2, df3`. When dumping, use just `df_dicts`.

Comment: Should `with open..."wb"` be followed by an `f.close()`?

Comment: @Dan [`with`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) takes care of it for you!